# Pentaho Report Designer: Change column value if output-format is excel

Tags: excel, pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Helo, I have report, where I show some photos. However, if the report is generated as Excel output, I don't want to have the photos there, because the size of generated file is too big in that case.

Because of that, I want to have those columns empty, if the output format is Excel (or, even not HTML would work). I have tried to do it through excel:formula in Attributes section of the cell, but it did not work (I guess, it is because its the formula of that excel cell.

I have also tried to create Open formula with `IF` statement, but wasn't able to find any way how to give it `output-format` as an parameter.

Is there any way how to solve this issue? How to change value of a cell depending on output-format? I been trying to find it in Pentaho documentation, but no luck so far..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the element you don't want to show and under `size & position` -> `visible`, add an OpenFormula by clicking the (+) and add a formula like this:

```py
=NOT(ISEXPORTTYPE("table/excel"))
```

The available export types can be looked up at `Master Report` -> `Attributes` -> `output-format`.

When previewing as e.g. "HTML" and "Excel", the output format will automatically be set accordingly, so you can simply hit preview without changing that value every time.